# Parse xml having different tags using sax parser

Tags: java

i am having problem with parsing the xml which has different tags.Below is the xml that i want to parse and what i want is that data in primary is stored in seperate data structure and data in secondary tag is stored in different data structure.can anyone help.thanks in advance.

```
<Alerts>
  <Secondary>
    <FIRST_NAME>aaa</FIRST_NAME>
    <EquicomAlerts>
      <channelAlertStates>
        <alertStates channel="ONLINE">
          <state name="CREATED" date="2012-01-11" />
        </alertStates>
      </channelAlertStates>
    </EquicomAlerts>
  </Secondary>
  <Primary>
    <FIRST_NAME>bbb</FIRST_NAME>
    <EquicomAlerts>
      <channelAlertStates>
        <alertStates channel="OffLINE">
          <state name="Destroyed" date="2012-01-11" />
        </alertStates>
      </channelAlertStates>
    </EquicomAlerts>
  </Primary>
</Alerts>
```

Comment: Your difficulty is not so clear, so I'm assuming you have not used SAX before. I posted an answer - hopes it hit the spot.

Comment: you should be a lot more specific when you say "i am having problem" . what kind of problem ?? what version of java are you using? do you see an exception? if you do, by all means share it with us ... do you need specific data from your xml? an object model? i bet there are lots of people willing to help but first we need to understand what your problem is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using SAX for parsing XML you need to implement a `ContentHandler`.
The `ContentHandler` gets events when the parser hits any node in the XML.

You need to see when you get an event for starting the `Primary` element, and put everything the parser finds in the appropriate data structure.

Once you are notified by the parser that the `Secondary` element began - you should switch to the 2nd data structure.

You should read a bit about SAX parsers to learn how to implement it correctly.

If your document is not too large - I recommend using DOM instead, it will be easier for you to implement.

Edit:
I'm answering from my phone, so please excuse any mistakes.

SAX is an event driven manner to parse your XML.
You will need to implement methods like `startElement`, `endElement` and  `readCharacters` (probably got the name of the last one wrong). Each of these serves a purpose - you should read about them. Basically your content handler needs to receive those events and handles the reading of data accordingly.

try writing a sample content handler and debug it to understand how it works - that is the best advice I can give you.

Comment: hey can u help..I am not getting the idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in the question. If you know how to parse an xml using Java, then what you are asking is simple to achieve. Based on the Tag name, you need to populate the data structure of your choice. The following code might not be optimal but works. There are a number of xml-to-java binding frameworks like jaxb, castor, xmlbeans etc. You can use anyone of them to make your life simple. You can use xpath api for parsing too.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ExampleDOMParser  {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = db.parse("test.xml"); //Feed your XML..

            Node rootNode = dom.getChildNodes().item(0);
            NodeList nodeList = rootNode.getChildNodes();
            for(int i=0;i < nodeList.getLength();i++){
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName());
                Node childNode = nodeList.item(i);

                if(childNode.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE &&
                        childNode.getNodeName().equals("Secondary")){
                    // TODO: Drill down using DOM API to populate your datastructure
                }
                else if(childNode.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE &&
                        childNode.getNodeName().equals("Primary")){
                    //TODO: Drill down using DOM API to populate your datastructure
                }

            }

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You write a XSLT through which you can put the data of the input XML into separate structure as per your requirement and parsing XML through XSLT is very easy